# what the trim and str_replace in autoload function do?

Tags: php

I'm studying on autoloading. I found this line of code where trim and str_replace do the same thing which is getting rid of backslash(on my undestanding).

But I don't understand why they need to do this?

Can someone explain?

```
$class = 'One\Ting\ming';

strtolower(str_replace("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, trim($class, "\\"))).".php";
```

Comment: `trim` only removes chars from start and end. `str_replace` replaces all occurrences in the string.

Comment: One normally looks these things up [in the manual](http://php.net/docs.php)

Comment: @bansi, on what occasion they nee to remove the backslash? I don't think for the above $class string they remove any. They still echo the same string but lowercased after str_replace and trim occured.

Comment: They are removing 2 backslash and converting to single `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` think if you want your class as `$class = 'One\\Ting\ming\';`

Comment: @RiggsFolly nowadays people treat manual as their enemy, when it is the only friend in need.

Answer (score 0):

The `trim` removes the backslash at the start of the string.
Then the `str_replace` replaces all other backslashes with the constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`.

For argument sake, let us say your `DIRECTORY SEPARATOR` is `/`.

```
$class = '\One\Ting\ming'; \\ notice that I have added a leading backslash

strtolower(str_replace("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, trim($class, "\\"))).".php";
```

After trimming the leading backslash, becomes

```
strtolower(str_replace("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, "One\Ting\ming")).".php";
```

Then changing all occurrences of `\` to `/`, it becomes

```
strtolower("One/Ting/ming").".php";
```

Finally, changing the string to all lowercase and appending the file extension, it becomes

```
"one/ting/ming.php";
```

Comment: Your explanation is valid but the code piece is totally lame. always better to use `/` for directory separator (works across all platforms). think what happens if `$class = "\One\ting\ming";`

Comment: @bansi Sweeping statements are always false. The example you just gave is the one applied here. You can discuss WHY it is better or worse to use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, but the truth is that `/` only works because windows allows you to use the wrong directory separator (and PHP converts \ to / in its file functions anyway). By doing it correctly (using the constant), you are future proof for if/when a system decides that `(^.^)` is the new directory separator.